# Сгенерировать все возможные комбинации из заглавных и строчных букв

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5

Как получить все возможные комбинации **из заглавных и строчных букв** в слове **не меняя их порядок**.
К примеру имеем слово на входе

```
abc12
```

А на выходе получим

```
abc12
abC12
aBc12
aBC12
Abc12
AbC12
ABc12
ABC12
```

Comment: Проще всего сделать рекурсивную процедуру. На каждом уровне проверяем соответствующий символ, и если он буква, то вызываем следующий уровень два раза, добавляя к выходной строке маленькую и большую версию символа, иначе только один вызов с неизмененным символом